# How to change pagers width when window size changes?

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider

I have this HTML code for bx-slider pager

```
<div id="bx-custom-pager">               
      <a data-slide-index="0" href="" style=""><div class="bx-item" style="" id="i1"></div></a>
      <a data-slide-index="1" href="" style=""><div class="bx-item" style="" id="i2"></div></a>
      <a data-slide-index="2" href="" style=""><div class="bx-item" style="" id="i3"></div></a>
      <a data-slide-index="3" href="" style=""><div class="bx-item" style="" id="i4"></div></a>
      <a data-slide-index="4" href="" style=""><div class="bx-item" style="" id="i5"></div></a>
</div>
```

and I writed a JQuery code to resize pagers width when resize window width

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var item = document.getElementsByClassName('bx-item');
    item.each(function detectwidth(){
         item.style.width = 100 / 5 + 'px';
    });
    window.onresize = function (){
         detectwidth();
    };
});
```

but it doesn't work and doesn't resize the pagers ...
any help please ..?

Answer (score 0):

try

$( window ).resize(function() { ...
 $(this)...

https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: doesn't work too,but  when i try `document.getElementById('i1')` it works well but only for first pager ..

Comment: So the code works when I call the item by Id ... how can I call the whole items (pagers) and resize them all ...

Comment: since jQuery does not work for you else you could have tried $(document).find("*").

else try this 

document.getElementsByTagName("*");

Comment: Okay
the code show me this error "TypeError: item.style is undefined"
why?

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave tries to set them to 20px width which I guess is just for the example. Here's a working version of that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $('.bx-item').width(100/5);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/re958rfL/)**

I suspect you may be iterating for a reason (perhaps they should have different widths), in which case you would use .each().

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $('.bx-item').each(function(i){
            $(this).width(100/(i+1));
        });
    });
});
```

or declare width using an anonymous function

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $('.bx-item').width(function(i){
            return 100/(i+1); // or some other calculation
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two issues in your code. First, you are trying to use item.each, but item is not a jQuery object. Second, in your `detectwidth` function, you're setting the width for each `.bx-item`, but you're not dividing the window width properly.

please click on below demo link.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaypancholi2626/cehogzd5/4/)

```
<div id="bx-custom-pager">               
    <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><div class="bx-item" id="i1"></div></a>
    <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><div class="bx-item" id="i2"></div></a>
    <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><div class="bx-item" id="i3"></div></a>
    <a data-slide-index="3" href=""><div class="bx-item" id="i4"></div></a>
    <a data-slide-index="4" href=""><div class="bx-item" id="i5"></div></a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Function to set the width of each pager item
        function detectWidth() {
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            var numItems = 5; // Number of pager items

            $('.bx-item').css('width', windowWidth / numItems + 'px');
        }

        // Initial call to set the width on document ready
        detectWidth();

        // Call the detectWidth function on window resize
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            detectWidth();
        });
    });
</script>
```